# Rails Stripe Gem - page needs to be refreshed before payment will process

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

I'm currently building an Events site using rails. I'm using the Stripe gem to process payments. Everything seems to be working fine other than whenever I want to make a payment (in test/development mode at present) I have to refresh the page and re-enter payment details before the payment will process. There's no error code coming up but it happens every time.

What could be causing this? Here's the relevant code -

bookings_controller.rb

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController

before_action :authenticate_user!

def new
    # booking form
    # I need to find the event that we're making a booking on
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    # and because the event "has_many :bookings"
    @booking = @event.bookings.new
    # which person is booking the event?
    @booking.user = current_user
    #@booking.quantity = @booking.quantity
    #@total_amount = @booking_quantity.to_f * @event_price.to_f

end

def create
    # actually process the booking
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @booking = @event.bookings.new(booking_params)
    @booking.user = current_user
    #@total_amount = @booking.quantity.to_f * @event.price.to_f

    Booking.transaction do
        @booking.save!
        @event.reload
        if @event.bookings.count > @event.number_of_spaces
            flash[:warning] = "Sorry, this event is fully booked."
            raise ActiveRecord::Rollback, "event is fully booked"
        end 
    end

    if @booking.save

        # CHARGE THE USER WHO'S BOOKED
        # #{} == puts a variable into a string
        Stripe::Charge.create(amount: @event.price_pennies, currency: "gbp",
            card: @booking.stripe_token, description: "Booking number #{@booking.id}")

        flash[:success] = "Your place on our event has been booked"
        redirect_to event_path(@event)
    else
        flash[:error] = "Payment unsuccessful"
        render "new"
    end

    if @event.is_free?

        @booking.save!
        flash[:success] = "Your place on our event has been booked"
        redirect_to event_path(@event)
    end
end


#def total_amount
    #@total_amount = @booking.quantity * @event.price
#end

private

def booking_params
    params.require(:booking).permit(:stripe_token, :quantity)
end



end
```

new.html.erb (bookings)

```
    <% if @event.is_free? %>
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" id="eventshow">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h2>Your Booking Confirmation</h2>
        </div>
                <div class="panel-body">

                        <h1>Hi there</h1>

                        <p>You have placed a booking on <%= @event.title %></p>

                        <p>Your order number is <%= @booking.id %></p>

                        <p>We hope you have a wonderful time. Enjoy!</p>

                        <p>Love from Mama Knows Best</p>
                </div>        
                  <div class="panel-footer">
                    <%= link_to "Home", root_path %>
                  </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>                      

                <% else %>

<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" id="eventshow">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h2>Confirm Your Booking</h2>
        </div>

            <div class="panel-body">    

                <p>Total Amount<%= @event.price %></p>
                <%= simple_form_for [@event, @booking], id: "new_booking" do |form| %>





                 <span class="payment-errors"></span>

                <div class="form-row">
                    <label>
                      <span>Card Number</span>
                      <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number"/>
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-row">
                  <label>
                  <span>CVC</span>
                  <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc"/>
                  </label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-row">
                    <label>
                        <span>Expiration (MM/YYYY)</span>
                        <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp-month"/>
                    </label>
                    <span> / </span>
                    <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="exp-year"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">    

               <%= form.button :submit %>


            </div> 

<% end %>
<% end %>

      </div>
  </div>
</div>    

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  // This identifies your website in the createToken call below
  Stripe.setPublishableKey('<%= STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY %>');
  // ...
  var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
  var $form = $('#new_booking');
  if (response.error) {
    // Show the errors on the form
    $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    // token contains id, last4, and card type
    var token = response.id;
    // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="booking[stripe_token]" />').val(token));
    // and re-submit
    $form.get(0).submit();
  }
};

jQuery(function($) {
  $('#new_booking').submit(function(e) {
    var $form = $(this);
    // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
    $form.find('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
    Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);
    // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
    return false;
  });
});


</script>
```

Here's the output from the terminal when I click on 'create booking' the first time before I refresh -

```
Started GET "/events/23/bookings/new" for ::1 at 2016-07-28 16:09:14 +0100
Processing by BookingsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"event_id"=>"23"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  Event Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 23]]
  Rendered bookings/new.html.erb within layouts/application (4.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 132ms (Views: 128.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

I'm sure it's a simple fix but can't figure it out. Any assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this part:

```
@booking.save!
@event.reload
```

You use `reload` but actually you are not creating the event in that moment, so I think you don't need to load the event in that way. You are booking the event. Try to removing the `reload`.

Can you copy and paste the output of the terminal when you try to make the payment at the first time (without refreshing the page)

Some references: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/reload

Comment: Hi, I've updated the question to include the terminal output above. Let me know what you think. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Hi, have you been able to take a further look at the question now I've added the development log? I've tried a few fixes on this but its still doing it.